# Applying shape keys through mesh data transfer plugin

Tags: shape-keys

I'm trying to transfer shape keys from one mesh to another I'm creating to load in a game.

Using the mesh data transfer plugin I transfer shape keys from the source mesh to my created piece. The two meshes are almost the same but they are sectioned into parts and each has different shape keys.

Shape keys seem to successfully transfer and function normally within Blender but upon loading the mesh in the game it appears broken beyond redemption.

Any idea why this is happening and how to avoid/fix this issue?